# inline color box delete inline div content when closed

Tags: javascript, jquery, colorbox

I have a colorbox showing an inline DOM element.

It works fine first time colorbox is showed, but if I close it and try to open again then it doesn't work.

When colorbox is created then child elements of #my-content-div is deleted and a display: none is added to #my-content-div and color box showed ok. But #my-content-div content is not revered.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div style="display: none;">
        <div id="my-content-div">
            My content!!
        </div>
</div>

<input type="button" id="show-my-content" value="Click to show my content">
```

my JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#show-my-content').live('click', function(){
        $.colorbox({
            inline: true,
            href: "#my-content-div"
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: live using for js binding is because the used jquery version. I can't change it for this project :-(

Answer (score 0):

try changing the `.live()` to `.on`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#show-my-content').on('click', function(){
        $.colorbox({
            inline: true,
            href: "#my-content-div"
        });
    });
});
```

As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live().

src: [jQuery .live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

Comment: Thanks Kevin. This project uses an old version of jquery. Delegate doesn't work (doesn't make the js binding). By the way, 'on' is not the problem here because colorbox is open first time, and second time colorbox is created but with an empty element. Namely, js binding is working :-)

Comment: can't seem to reproduce the problem here is my code if you click the settings tab on javascript field and set FRAMEWORKS & EXTENSIONS to the older jQuery available: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kevin_kloet/6a3r88dq/1/)